# "tar: not found in archive" error when using docker Alpine

Tags: tar, alpine-linux

I run these command:

```
docker run -ti --rm alpine
apk add --no-cache curl
curl https://registry.npmjs.org/monaco-editor/-/monaco-editor-0.15.6.tgz | tar xvz --strip 1 package/min
```

and got error `tar: package/min: not found in archive`.

I run the same command (curl | tar) in Mac terminal and docker ubuntu, all of them are success.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `tar` included in Alpine isn't the usual (GNU) tar, but a component of BusyBox:

```
/scratch # tar --version
tar (busybox) 1.28.4
```

Apparently, this version of tar generates a (bogus) error message when run with

`tar xvz --strip 1 package/min`

(however, at first glance, it created the target directory just fine, so ignoring the error message might be ok).

To get rid of the annoying error, you should install GNU tar and use that:

```
/scratch # apk add --no-cache tar
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
(1/1) Installing tar (1.31-r0)
Executing busybox-1.28.4-r2.trigger
OK: 7 MiB in 19 packages
/scratch # tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.31
<rest of message omitted>
```

Afterwards, running your original command works without any error messages.

Comment: Except we did that and it didn't work.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle What exactly didn't work? Were you unable to install GNU tar? Did the installation work, but calling tar still executed the busybox version?

Comment: I was able to install GNU tar but it still gives me errors trying to untar anything, helm, google sdk, etc. I don't know why I came across this post to begin with but the OP is not exactly my problem at the moment.

Comment: @NathanMcKaskle Then I'd suggest you ask a separate question on SO